# Getting error in retrolambda error in android studio 1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, retrolambda

I am working in android studio 1.0

the gradle file is showing this error:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetroLambdaDebug'

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'retrolambda'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.0'

}
```

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.4.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
     } 
}
```

what else changes I have to make in the gradle file. Please suggest something...

Comment: Please supply more details on the error message you're getting.

Comment: I am using studio on windows and it is giving me only error which is app:compileRetroLambdaDebug.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while updating the dependencies in eclipse. Try to update to the newest plugin versions and change `retrolambda` to `me.tatarka.retrolambda`, since the `retrolambda` plugin is deprecated and will be removed soon. At least it's what I did to fix the error.

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.5.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

...
```